# Null Label Content in DialogBox (WPF)

Tags: wpf, null, dialog, label, box

I am a beginner in WPF. I have an application with a main window and a dialog box. When I the load dialog box, I put a number (fetched from database) in the content of a label in my dialog box. Everything goes well, and I can see the fetched number, in label of the dialog box, but when I try to use it for fetching some data in my dialog box, WPF says the label content is null.
I put a number as content of the idNum. It worked properly. So I think there is no problem for my codes, but I can't understand why it is "null" although it is shown in dlg.lbId.

In my code behind of my main window I have:

```
    private void btManage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selected = lvOwnerCar.SelectedItem as Owner;
        int selectedId = selected.Id;
        string selectedName = selected.Name;
        CarsDialog dlg = new CarsDialog();
        dlg.lbName.Content = selectedName;
        dlg.lbId.Content = selectedId;
        dlg.Owner = this;
        dlg.ShowDialog();
    }
```

and in the code behind of dialog box I have:

```
        public CarsDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ctx = new CarDbContext();
        lvCars.ItemsSource = (from c in ctx.Cars select c).ToList<Car>();
        int idNum = Convert.ToInt32(lbId.Content);
        lvCars.ItemsSource = (from c in ctx.Cars where c.Owner.Id == idNum select c).ToList<Car>();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue can be that you are trying to read `lbId.Content` before it's really set. Try to move loading data from the constructor of `CarsDialog` to a method let's `LoadData`. Call `LoadData` before `ShowDialog`. You can get rid of the line `lvCars.ItemsSource = (from c in ctx.Cars select c).ToList<Car>();` and keep only the second query.

CarsDialog code behind:

```
public CarsDialog()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void LoadData()
{
    ctx = new CarDbContext();
    int idNum = Convert.ToInt32(lbId.Content);
    lvCars.ItemsSource = (from c in ctx.Cars where c.Owner.Id == idNum select c).ToList<Car>();
}
```

MainWindow code behind:

```
private void btManage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var selected = lvOwnerCar.SelectedItem as Owner;
    int selectedId = selected.Id;
    string selectedName = selected.Name;
    CarsDialog dlg = new CarsDialog();
    dlg.lbName.Content = selectedName;
    dlg.lbId.Content = selectedId;
    dlg.Owner = this;
    dlg.LoadData();
    dlg.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest mistake concerns violation of OOP principles. All UI elements of a window are private details of its implementation and must be encapsulated.
For public communication, you must declare public methods and properties.

And a smaller detail.
Why are you using a Label and not a TextBlock to display plain text?

An example of a more correct implementation(part of the code related to the question):

```
public class CarsDialog
{
    public CarsDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ctx = new CarDbContext();
        lvCars.ItemsSource = (from c in ctx.Cars select c).ToList<Car>();
    }

    private int _idNum;
    public int IdNum
    {
        get => _idNum;
        set
        {
            lbId.Content = _idNum = value;
            ctx = new CarDbContext();
            lvCars.ItemsSource = (from c in ctx.Cars where c.Owner.Id == idNum select c).ToList<Car>();
        }
    }

    private string _nameCar;
    public string NameCar
    {
        get => _nameCar;
        set
        {
            lbName.Content = _nameCar = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Using:

```
    private void btManage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selected = lvOwnerCar.SelectedItem as Owner;
        int selectedId = selected.Id;
        string selectedName = selected.Name;
        CarsDialog dlg = new CarsDialog();
        dlg.NameCar = selectedName;
        dlg.IdNum = selectedId;
        dlg.Owner = this;
        dlg.ShowDialog();
    }
```